# Low-rank matrix maximizing quadratic form

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, reference-request

I was wondering if anyone were familiar with optimization problems of the following form:
$$
%\underset{\textrm{rank}(A)\leq r}{\max} x
\max_{||A||\leq1,\;\textrm{rank}(A)\leq r} x^{\intercal}A^{\intercal}\Sigma A x
$$
Where $x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is a fixed, known vector, $\Sigma$ is a fixed, known $n\times n$ symmetric positive semi-definite matrix.

I'm wondering if this problem has been studied and if anyone could point me towards references - my initial search turned up very little.

Edit:

So here is a possibility: first assume $A$ is full rank. Then we can just maximize $y^{\intercal}\Sigma y$. Once we find $y^{\ast}$ numerically, we find the matrix $A$ such that $y^{\ast} = Ax$. If $A$ is not full rank, we can just use the low-rank approximation of the full rank matrix found previously?

Edit 2:
Added Frobenius norm constraint as otherwise the solution is unbounded.

Comment: Your constraint on $A$ means that the maximum will always be $\infty$. In particular, if $x^TA^T\Sigma Ax > 0$ and the rank of $A$ is $r$, then for any $t > 0 $, $tA$ will be another rank-$r$ matrix where replacing $A$ with $tA$ the objective function is multiplies the result by $t^2$. As $t\to \infty$, this result is unbounded.

Comment: Perhaps you'd like to add a further constraint on $A$, such as $\|A\|_F \leq 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be the following rank-1 matrix:
$$
A = v_{\star} \cdot \left( \frac{x}{\|x\|} \right)^{\mathsf{T}}.
$$
where $v_{\star}$ is the principal eigenvector of $\Sigma$. Clearly,
$\|A\| = \|A\|_{\mathsf{F}} = 1$ and $Ax = v_{\star} \cdot \|x\|$.

Putting everything together, this yields
$$
\langle x, A^{\mathsf{T}} \Sigma A x \rangle =
\|x\|^2 \cdot \langle v_{\star}, \Sigma v_{\star} \rangle =
\|x\|^2 \|\Sigma\|.
$$

This is the optimal value of the optimization problem: indeed,

$$
\langle x, A^{\mathsf{T}} \Sigma A x \rangle =
\langle Ax, \Sigma Ax \rangle \leq \|Ax\| \cdot \|\Sigma Ax \| \leq
\|\Sigma\| \cdot \|Ax\|^2 \leq \|\Sigma\| \|A\|^2 \|x\|^2 \leq
\|\Sigma\| \|x\|^2.
$$